# Trouble getting array back from JSON call to SQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, json

Just trying to grab everything from a table "guesses" sorted by "cnt" and turn it into a javascript array. Can't get it to give me anything I can work with, though.

PHP file:

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = 'root'; 
$dbname = 'words'; 
$dbtable = 'guesses'; 

//------ DATABASE CONNECTION --------// 
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) 
or die ("Unable to connect to database"); 

mysql_select_db($dbname) 
or die ("Unable to select database"); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbtable ORDER BY cnt ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo json_encode($array);
}

?>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $.getJSON('grab.php', function(response) {
    // response is a JSON object that contains all the info from sql query
    // tried so much stuff here... no avail.
        console.log(response);
})
```

The console doesn't say anything.
"SELECT * FROM guesses ORDER BY cnt ASC" in the phpmyadmin console DOES return the correct entries and order.

EDIT: I've also tried

```
<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = 'root'; 
$dbname = 'words'; 
$dbtable = 'guesses'; 

//------ DATABASE CONNECTION --------// 
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) 
or die ("Unable to connect to database"); 

mysql_select_db($dbname) 
or die ("Unable to select database"); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbtable ORDER BY cnt ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Which might be syntactically better(???) but it returns "false" to console, and nothing else.

Comment: What are your fields in dbtable

Comment: id, word, cnt are my three fields

Comment: does alert(response.Id) do anything?

Comment: can only send one json string to client, you are sending for every pass of loop

Comment: alert(response.id) returns undefined

Comment: did you note the capital 'I' in my comment

Comment: where is `$dbtable` defined?

Comment: tried it both ways, i and I, no dice

Comment: $dbtable is defined in the PHP file at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding json at wrong place.

```
$arr=array();
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($arr,$array);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Try this

Comment: Hmm still returning false :/

Comment: when I console.log response, it just says false.

Comment: EUREKA! Well done. Now to figure out how to parse this so my front-end brain can make use of it. Ideas? ;-)

Comment: $.each over the response

Comment: Its better u try it first...:))

Comment: I ended up doing this: goodwords = $.map(response, function(el) {
   return [[el.word]];
  }); and it worked! thanks